# Expand/collapse a menu list with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what I'm trying to make:

[image: Visual aid]

1. Click on "PORTFOLIO";
2. Pushes everything down smoothly;
3. New links fade-in smoothly;
4. Click on "PORTFOLIO" again, do everything in reverse;

My current code;

```js
 $(function(){
 $('[data-toggle]').on('click', function(){
  var id = $(this).data("toggle"),
   $object = $(id),
   className = "open";

  if ($object) {
  if ($object.hasClass(className)) {
   $object.removeClass(className)
     } else {
   $object.addClass(className)
   }
  }
 });
 });
```

```css
 #list{
  display: none;
 }

 #list.open{
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">A Empresa</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" class="hide" data-toggle="#list">Portfolio</a>
             <ul id="list">
                 <li><a href="#">Comerciais</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Residenciais</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Institucionais</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Edifícios</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
     </ul>
 </nav>
```

It's possible to accomplish this without JS, only with CSS? I have no clue whatsoever how to do the animation part, I tried CSS Transitions propriety, but didn't work.

Also, any tips for the markup and JS? I don't thinks I'm doing it the "right way"... any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your problem? what does the code do that you do not need?

Comment: Not sure I get what troubles you. Is this what you want to achieve https://jsfiddle.net/L9f10vq6/1/ ?

Comment: @Albin To just expand and collapse and not change the text

Comment: @AdonaiCândido, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kjp174p3/1/ ?

Comment: @nevermind and faiakism yes! that did it! thanks! I didn't know that this was that simples... really new to JS. Thanks.

Comment: even easier js: http://jsfiddle.net/smhzcuq3/

Comment: Any tips for the markup? I thinks it's a little bit polluted.

Comment: @Albin :) http://jsfiddle.net/4jvmdLg6/

Comment: @Red2678 I admit to being defeated ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: Never mind someone answered your question in the comments.**

I am not sure I fully understand your question as it looks like your code works well.

I think that if you do not want to not have the text changed for the + and - you could add a new element/tag that shows that at the end of the list items.

I am not so grate at JS but the text() or html() can be used on a span within the list text that way it does not get changed.

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>A Empresa</li>
    <li><a href="#" id="item3link" style="text-decoration: none; text-color:Black;">Portfolio <span id="item3icon">+</span></a>
        <ul id="list" class="subClassHide">
            <li>Comerciais</li>
            <li>Residenciais</li>
            <li>Institucionais</li>
            <li>Edifícios</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contato</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('#item3link').on('click', function(){
if (toggleOn == 1) {
    toggleOn = 0;
    $('#item3icon').html('+');
    $('#list').addClass("subClassHide");
}
else
{
    toggleOn = 1;
    $('#item3icon').html('-');
    $('#list').removeClass("subClassHide");
}
});
var toggleOn = 0;
```

CSS:
(I changed this a bit but it is not important, it was just close to the solution I had locally)

```
.subClassHide {
display: none;
}
```

```js
$('#item3link').on('click', function() {
  if (toggleOn == 1) {
    toggleOn = 0;
    $('#item3icon').html('+');
    $('#list').addClass("subClassHide");
  } else {
    toggleOn = 1;
    $('#item3icon').html('-');
    $('#list').removeClass("subClassHide");
  }
});

var toggleOn = 0;
```

```css
.subClassHide {
  display: none;
}

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900);
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-highlight: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition: all .15s ease;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
}

nav:before,
nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  height: .3em;
  width: 1.2em;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav>ul>li {
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

#list li {
  color: #800;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

#list li:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: #800;
  height: 2px;
  width: .4em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -.8em;
}

#list.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>A Empresa</li>
    <li><a href="#" id="item3link" style="text-decoration: none; text-color:Black;">Portfolio <span id="item3icon">+</span></a>
      <ul id="list" class="subClassHide">
        <li>Comerciais</li>
        <li>Residenciais</li>
        <li>Institucionais</li>
        <li>Edifícios</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contato</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

If I misunderstood I hope this post will (at the least) give you ideas.